# Angular Expression not recognized. Program not working

Tags: javascript, angularjs, module

I'm trying to create a front-end application that presents the user with a textbox where they can list comma-separated items they usually eat for lunch. Once that's entered, the user has to click the "Check If Too Much" button.

I'm a beginner, don't have a great grasp of Angular yet. My program doesn't work. For one, the expressions are not being recognized when I interpolate them in HTML. Not sure why.

I think there may be something wrong with the placement of my directives, but not really sure, could really use some help.

```js
(function () {
'use-strict';

angular.module('lunchCheck', [])
  .controller('LunchCheckController', function ($scope) {


    $scope.numberitems = function () {
      var itemstring = $scope.items
      var lunchItems = itemstring.split(",")
      return length.lunchItems
    };

    $scope.statement = function () {
      if ($scope.numberitems==0) {
        return "Please enter data first!"
      }
      else if (0<$scope.numberitems<5) {
        return "Enjoy!"
      }
      else if ($scope.numberitems>4) {
        return "Too much!"
      }
    };

  });

})();
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en" ng-app="lunchCheck">
  <head>
    <title>Lunch Checker</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/bootstrap.min.css">
    <style>
      .message { font-size: 1.3em; font-weight: bold; }
    </style>
  </head>
<body>
   <div class="container" ng-controller="LunchCheckController">
     <h1>Lunch Checker</h1>

         <div class="form-group">
             <input id="lunch-menu" type="text"
             placeholder="list comma separated dishes you usually have for lunch"
             class="form-control"
             ng-model="items">
         </div>

         <div class="form-group">
             <button
             class="btn btn-default"
             ng-click="statement">Check If Too Much</button>
         </div>

         <div class="form-group message" ng-click="statement">
           {{statement}}
         </div>
   </div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: where is `angular.js` reference on the page?

Comment: statement is a function  so you need to use it as a function with the `()`

Answer (score 0):

Both `$scope.numberitems` and `$scope.statement` are defined as functions. You'll need to execute the functions to get the results. First, call the `numberitems` function to get the count within `$scope.statement`.

```
$scope.statement = function () {
  var numberOfItems = $scope.numberitems()

  if (numberOfItems===0) {
    return "Please enter data first!"
  }
  else if (numberOfItems > 0 && numberOfItems < 5) {
    return "Enjoy!"
  }
  else if (numberOfItems > 4) {
    return "Too much!"
  }
};
```

Then, in your view, call the function.

`{{ statement() }}`

This is untested, but something like that should get you closer.

Answer (score 0):

There are many different issues with the code you showed.

**Not calling fuctions in ng-click:**
for `ng-click`, the fuction must be invoked like `ng-click="statement()"`.

**length. in numberitems function:** change it to `lunchItems.length`

**else if (0 < $scope.numberitems<5):** `0` here makes no difference

**using statement as function and value:** create a function to update the value inside the variable and use the variable to show it.

I'd also suggest to initialize your variables, like:

```
.controller('LunchCheckController', function ($scope) {
     $scope.statement = '';
     $scope.items = '';`
```

---

I've made a fiddle with what I supposed was the expected result:

[click for fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/wj00n4gr/)

Answer (score 0):

Used your code and did some changes.

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en" ng-app="lunchCheck">

<head>
  <title>Lunch Checker</title>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.5.9/angular.js"></script>
  <style>
    .message {
      font-size: 1.3em;
      font-weight: bold;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="container" ng-controller="LunchCheckController">
    <h1>Lunch Checker</h1>

    <div class="form-group">
      <input id="lunch-menu" type="text" placeholder="list comma separated dishes you usually have for lunch" class="form-control" ng-model="items">
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
      <button class="btn btn-default" ng-click="statement()">Check If Too Much</button>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group message">
      {{ istoomuch }}
    </div>
  </div>
  <script>
    (function() {
      'use-strict';

      angular.module('lunchCheck', [])
        .controller('LunchCheckController', function($scope) {
          $scope.istoomuch = '';

          $scope.numberitems = function() {
            if ($scope.items) { 
              var itemstring = $scope.items
              var lunchItems = itemstring.split(",")
              return lunchItems.length;
            } else {
              return 0;
            }
          };

          $scope.statement = function() {
            var totalitems = $scope.numberitems();
            console.log(totalitems);
            if (totalitems === 0) {
              $scope.istoomuch = "Please enter data first!"
            } else if (totalitems < 5) {
              $scope.istoomuch = "Enjoy!"
            } else if (totalitems > 4) {
              $scope.istoomuch = "Too much!"
            }
          };

        });

    })();
  </script>

</body>

</html>
```